# Magento2.3.5: Add note after custom attribute in product form fields

Tags: product-attribute, uicomponent, magento2.3.5

I need to display a message to admin in front of a custom product attribute.
For example " Sync Inventory with P21" fields when yes,( it sync inventory) I need to display a message to admin that says
"Match" otherwise "No Match"
It's dynamic and I have code for it.

[image]

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="update_stock" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\UpdateButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

> Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/UpdateButton.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Generic;

  class UpdateButton extends Generic {
      public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context $context
      )
      {
          $this->_coreRegistry      = $registry;
          $this->_product           = $product;
          parent::__construct($context,$registry);
      }
  public function getButtonData()
  {
          $message = __('Are you sure you want to do this?');
          return [
                'label' => __('Update'),
                'on_click' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$this->_updateProductStock()}')",
                'sort_order' => 10,
                'class' => 'action-secondary',
            ];
  }

  Public function _updateProductStock()
  {
          $url = $this->getUrl('inventory/index/custom' , ['entity_id' => $this->_getProductId()]);
          return $url;
  }

  Public function _getProductId()
  {
          $productId = $this->_product->loadByAttribute('entity_id', $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')
                                                                                         ->getId())->getdata('entity_id');
          return $productId;
    }
}
```

> Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Custom.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @param MagentoFrameworkViewElementUiComponentContext    $context
     * @param MagentoCatalogModelProduct                       $product
     * @param MagentoStoreModelAppEmulation                    $emulation
     * @param MagentoCatalogModelProductRepository             $productRepository
     * @param MagentoCatalogInventoryApiStockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
     * @param MagentoFrameworkMessageManagerInterface          $messageManager
     * @param array                                            $data
     */

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_stockRegistry     = $stockRegistry;
        $this->messageManager     = $messageManager;
        $this->_coreRegistry      = $registry;
        $this->_product           = $product;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    Public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect     = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        $id                 = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');
        $inventory_with_p21 = $this->_product->load($id)->getdata('sync_inventory_with_p21');
        try{
        $p21inventory = $this->_getProductInventory();
        $xml          = simplexml_load_string($p21inventory);
        $p21inventory = $xml->ItemAvailability[0]->QuantityOnHand;
        $product      = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
        $stockItem    = $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($product->getSku());
        $stockItem->setQty($p21inventory);
        $this->_stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($product->getSku(), $stockItem);
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Stock has been Updated.');
            }
        catch(Exception $e)
            {
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
            }
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

    Public function _getProductInventory()
    {
        $id      = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');
        $token   = $this->_apiOuth();
        $sku     = $this->_product->load($id)->getdata('sku');;
        $baseUrl = "https://api.guardiansafetyholdings.com:48080/";
        $ch      = curl_init($baseUrl."api/inventory/parts/$sku/availability?locationId=11");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer " . $token));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result  = curl_exec($ch);
        $info    = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please upload your code.

Comment: @RohanHapani I have updated my Question with my code.